# how to check if a link of an input belongs to a specific site in python?

Tags: python

I have a function that will check a URL `input`, however, there are only two options, which are Amazon and Aliexpress, so I'm trying to check if the link entered in the `input` belongs to one of the two sites, but I'm not getting it

```
def url_check(values):
    amazon_url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
    aliexpress_url = 'https://best.aliexpress.com/'
    
    if amazon_url not in values['url_input']:
        sg.popup_error('URL Error','The URL does not belong to the specified site!')
        raise ValueError('The URL does not belong to the specified site!')

    if not aliexpress_url in values['url_input']:
        sg.popup_error('URL Error','The URL does not belong to the specified site!')
        raise ValueError('The URL does not belong to the specified site!')
```

Note: I can't use `==` instead of `in` because the input will specify the link to a product from one of the sites, not the home url of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fully understand what you're asking or what's the problem, but you are always throwing errors if the provided site does not belong to amazon. You should cycle over all the sites that you want to check and raise an exception only if there is no match

```py
def url_check(values):
    valid_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com', 'https://best.aliexpress.com/']
    for url in valid_urls:
        if url in values['url_input']:
            return  # or do whatever

    sg.popup_error('URL Error','The URL does not belong to the specified site!')
    raise ValueError('The URL does not belong to the specified site!')
```

Comment: what I'm trying is to check if the link that will be input belongs to one of the two sites, if it doesn't belong to any throw the exception. I'll try that now and get back with the answer

Comment: also ensure that values is a dictionary and values['url_input'] is a string. If it still doesn't work, please provide details on the error

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Could you provide any details on the error or the unwanted behavior?

Comment: `values` is a dictionary that contains the values of a pysimplegui window, and `['url_input']` is the key. I tried your code and added an `else` to the `if` with the `raise` shown in the code, and it's always coming up to the `else`

Comment: oops, something unexpected happened. I added a print to `if url in values['url_input']` and it is printing and still getting to the else

Comment: Sure, if you add an `else` statement you will always raise exception if it doesn't match the first site of the list (in this case amazon). The concept is that you call this funnction to check the input, if it matches any website of the list it does nothing (return) and you can continue outside the function; if it doesn't match any of them it raise exception

Comment: aaah now i understand!! It worked!